# Thawte SSL123 SHA-2 Intermediate Certificate Chain, Broken?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, hash

I attempted to upgrade my one Web site, running `nginx`, from a SHA-1 SSL123 certificate to a SHA-2 one.

Thawte's [Web page with intermediate CAs](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR1384) has "RSA SHA-2  (under SHA-1 Root)" and "RSA SHA-2  (under SHA-2 Root)" tables.

If I use [the CA bundle](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR2157) for "under SHA-1 Root", I see that the bundle contains two certificates, and my Web site works. However, Qualys' SSL Test rightfully dings me for having a SHA-2 certificate with SHA-1 in the certificate chain.

However, the "under SHA-2 Root" table does not have bundles. If I use [the single intermediate certificate](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR2158) they supply there, Firefox and other tools point out that the certificate chain is broken, and browsers won't load my site.

Right now, I'm using the SHA-1 root, to have a working site. However, I would like to switch to the SHA-2 root.

Where do I get the missing intermediate certificate? Or, if that's not the problem, how do I create a combined certificate file for Thawte's SSL123 fro a SHA-2 certificate with a full chain of SHA-2 intermediate certificates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Thawte's site is just confusing for people who don't work with SSL certs a lot.

Despite the fact that there are two certificates shown for [SSL123 SHA2 under SHA-1 Root](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR2156), you only need the first one. The second certificate *is* the SHA-1 root, and you don't need it concatenated with your site's cert for deployment to `nginx`. Just use the first certificate, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your own certificate is signed by exactly one certificate.

This means that your certificate is at one end of exactly one of these Thawte chains, you would need a different certificate to be in the other chain (one signed by the intermediate certificate from that chain).

As for the signature of the *root certificate* being SHA-1, SHA-2 or something else it is of little consequence compared to other certificates in the chain as the validating party already has the root certificates that they trust, they do not need a signature to check the roots. (See eg [SHA1 Deprecation: What You Need to Know](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know).)

Examining the certificates in the [Thawte SSL123 SHA-2 (under SHA1-Root)](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR2156) chain it turns out that one of the intermediate certificates ("Primary Intermediate CA") is also SHA-1 (not only the root). It is almost assuredly this certificate that you are getting "dinged" for. You'll need to get Thawte to issue you a new certificate signed by the intermediate certificate from the other chain to resolve this.

Comment: That makes sense. What doesn't make sense is why Thawte would be issuing certs that go up the SHA-1 chain here in December 2014. I'll see if I get some tech support love on this one on Monday, and I'll circle back to this question if they confirm what you're saying. Many thanks!